# Image Upload does not work in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I'm having trouble to upload image on my local server.

I just started learning Codeigniter referencing https://www.phptpoint.com/Codeigniter-upload-file-image/ and Codeigniter documentation.

I followed each step but when I click upload button then, I can't open the page. safari says "Failed to open the page" error.

There should be some mistake I've made in the code.

Does anyone find it, please?

PS: I even got error when not attaching image. maybe the error is not about uploading image?

```
<?php 
class ImageUpload_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    //load Helper for Form
    $this->load->helper('url'); 
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('imageupload_form');
    }

    public function upload() 
    {
        $new_name = date('ymd') . time();
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '2000';
        $config['max_width'] = '1500';
        $config['max_height'] = '1500';
        $config['file_name']  = $new_name;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (! $this->upload->do_upload('profile_pic')) 
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('imageupload_form', $error);
        } 
        else 
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('imageupload_success', $data);
        }
    }

}
?>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload Image in Codeigniter</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    // I'm not sure but referenced website used "@" right before $error so I kept using. when omitted it I got errors
    <?php echo @$error; ?> 
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('imageupload_controller/upload');?>
    <?php echo "<input type='file' name='profile_pic' size='20' />"; ?>
    <?php echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='upload' /> ";?>
    <?php echo "</form>";?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where do you define `$path`?

Comment: Do I need to define ```$path``` in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I updated few lines in your code. Please run a command given below to make your directory with writable permission.

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/[new directory]
```

Add a variable name `$path = '/var/www/html/ur_project_directory/uploads;`
 on the first line after function start. And change `ur_project_directory` with your directory name.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the edit. Though I changed the file permission it still not working properly.

Comment: please add edits to your answer, instead of editing the question

Comment: is it showing any error in your view? I recently change your code please recheck with updated code.

Comment: Okay I will remember it. @LawrenceCherone

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines

```
if (!file_exists($path)) {
    mkdir($path, 0755, true);
}
```

I don't see any use case of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your working code after testing.

This is the view file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload Image in Codeigniter</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo @$error; ?> 
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('test/upload');?>
    <?php echo "<input type='file' name='profile_pic' size='20' />"; ?>
    <?php echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='upload' /> ";?>
    <?php echo "</form>";?>


    <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('status')) { ?>

     <label><?php  echo $this->session->flashdata('status'); ?></label>

    <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is your controller file

```html
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends MX_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //load Helper for Form
        $this->load->helper('url'); 
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('test-view');
    }

    public function upload() 
    {
        $new_name = date('ymd') . time();
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '2000';
        $config['max_width'] = '1500';
        $config['max_height'] = '1500';
        $config['file_name']  = $new_name;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (! $this->upload->do_upload('profile_pic')) 
        {
            $data = $this->upload->display_errors();
            
            $this->session->set_flashdata('status', $data);
            $this->load->view('test-view', $data);
        } 
        else 
        {
            $data = 'Your file uploaded sucessfully.';
            $this->session->set_flashdata('status', $data);
            $this->load->view('test-view', $data);
        }
    }

}
?>
```